# General State Space Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I am having some difficulty understanding some early results of Markov Chain theory on a general state space.

We have a function (Kernel) $K:E  \times  E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a distribution $\mu(x)$ such that

$P(X_{t} \in A\mid X_{t-1} = x) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{A}K(x,y)\text{d}y$, $ \ \ \text{and} \ \ $ $P(X\in A) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{A}\mu(x)\text{d}x$,

where $E$ is the set of all possible values of our chain.

Here is where I get stuck.

It then follows that

$P(X_{1}\in A_{1},..., X_{t}\in A_{t}) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{A_{1}\times\cdots\times A_{t}} \mu(x_{1})\prod\limits_{k=2}^{t}K(x_{k-1},x_{k})\text{d}x_{1}...\text{d}x_{t}$.

Which I am not quite able to follow through.

My attempt:

$P(X_{1}\in A_{1},..., X_{t}\in A_{t}) = P(X_{1}\in A_{1})\displaystyle\prod\limits_{k=2}^{t}P(X_{k}|X_{1}\in A_{1},..., X_{k-1}\in A_{k-1})$

$\hspace{4.7cm}= \displaystyle\int\limits_{A_{1}}\mu(x_{1})\text{d}x_{1}\prod\limits_{k=2}^{t}P(X_{k}|X_{k-1}\in A_{k-1})$,

which is almost what I am after.. except for the fact that I have a condition on $X_{k-1}\in A_{k-1}$, whereas the definition of $K$ is conditioned on $X_{t-1} = x_{t-1}$. And I am a little unsure what to do with the order of integration.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for your insights and thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is not very clear, so I am making it a bit more standard in my answer.

Let's look at two periods
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1 \right] & = & \int_{A_1} \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1
  \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2 \right] & = & \int_{A_1} \Pr \left[ X_2
  \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right] \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
But
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_2 \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right] & = & k \left( x_1, A_2 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_2} k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2 \right] & = & \int_{A_1} \int_{A_2} k
  \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
By induction, using the Markov property (for every $t$, $\Pr \left[ X_t \in A_t |X_1 \in A_1, \ldots, X_{t - 1} \in A_{t - 1} \right]= 
\Pr \left[ X_t \in A_t |X_{t - 1} \in A_{t - 1} \right]$), you could deduce that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1, \ldots, X_{t - 1} \in A_{t - 1}, X_t \in A_t \right]
  & = & \int_{A_1 \times \cdots \times A_{t - 1}} k \left( x_{t - 1}, A_t
  \right) k \left( x_{t - 2}, \mathrm{d} x_{t - 1} \right) \cdots k \left(
  x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1 \times \cdots \times A_{t - 1} \times A_t} k \left( x_{t -
  1}, \mathrm{d} x_t \right) k \left( x_{t - 2}, \mathrm{d} x_{t - 1} \right)
  \cdots k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1
  \right)\\
  &  & 
\end{eqnarray*}

---

Since you are having trouble understanding the reasoning, here is an over-detailed explanation without the induction argument

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2, X_3 \in A_3 \right] & = & \int_{A_1}
  \Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3, X_2 \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right] {d} \mu \left(
  x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1} \underbrace{\Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3 |X_2 \in A_2, X_1 = x_1
  \right] \Pr \left[ X_2 \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right]}_{= \Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3
  |X_2 \in A_2 \right] \Pr \left[ X_2 \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right]} {d}
  \mu \left( x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1} \left( \int_{A_2} \Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3 |X_2 = x_2
  \right] \Pr \left[ X_2 \in \mathrm{d} x_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right] \right)
  {d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1} \left( \int_{A_2} \Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3 |X_2 = x_2
  \right] k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left(
  x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1 \times A_2} \underbrace{\Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3 |X_2 = x_2
  \right]}_{= k \left( x_2, A_3 \right)} k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right)
  \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1 \times A_2} \left( \int_{A_3} k \left( x_2, \mathrm{d} x_3
  \right) \right) k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left(
  x_1 \right)\\
  & = & \int_{A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3} k \left( x_2, \mathrm{d} x_3 \right)
  k \left( x_1, \mathrm{d} x_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1 \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

The second line follows by Markov.

To progress further, it is a good investment to learn measure theory (e.g.  Rosenthal's "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory".

Comment: *By induction, you could deduce*... Sorry but nothing in the question allows to deduce that (one needs to add the Markov property as a *hypothesis*, to conclude).

Comment: Very sorry, but how did you get the first line in the three periods case?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: The only think here is, as Did pointed out, in the integrand, we omitted $X_1$ from $\Pr \left[ X_3 \in A_3 |X_2 = x_2, X_1 = x_1 \right]$ (thus exploiting the Markov property)

Comment: $P(X_{1}\in A_{1}, X_{2}\in A_{2}, X_{3}\in A_{3}) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{A_{1}}P(X_{3} \in A_{3},X_{2}\in A_{2}|X_{1}=x_{1})\text{d}(\mu(x_{1}))$. Do I start there? I may have to be spoon fed the solution, just this once.

Comment: Writing
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2, X_3 \in A_3 \right] & = & \int \Pr
  \left[ X_3 \in A_3, X_2 \in A_2 |X_1 = x_1 \right] \mathrm{d} \mu \left( x_1
  \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
is also correct bu then, you would not have exploited the computation of $\Pr
\left[ X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2 \right]$.

Comment: $P(X_{1}\in A_{1},X_{2}\in A_{2},X_{3}\in A_{3}) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{A_{3}}P(X_{1}\in A_{1},X_{2}\in A_{2}|X_{3}=x_{3})\text{d}\mu(x_{3})$. I don't see how this will give the solution i'm after.

Comment: @Delvesy No, the last thing you wrote is not going to get you the answer. Also, $\mu$ is the probability measure on $X_1$ not $X_3$. If you are still having difficulties, a good strategy is to take a good textbook on Markov chains and read about the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations.

Comment: @Learner I know the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations. I think my problem is more to do with fundamentals of probability. Please would you give a hint as where to start. Since $\mu$ is the probability measure on $X_{1}$, I do not know how else to start this, other than what my second comment reads.

Comment: @Delvesy Then, this is an investment that needs to be done. Rosenthal's "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory" is an excellent place to start. It is short, pedagogical and chapter 15 deals directly with your question.

Comment: @Learner. Will your recommended book also help with getting from line 2 to 3 in your detailed explanation? Thanks for all your help.